# How would I run a simulation based on percentage with Python?

Tags: python

I'm writing a program for a game me and my brother made, and this is what I have so far:

```
def main():
  number1 = requestInteger("Enter team 1 power:")
  print ("team 1 is " + str(number1) + " overall")  
  number2 = requestInteger("Enter team 2 power:")
  print ("team 2 is " + str(number2) + " overall")
  odds = number1 - number2
  print str(odds)
  favoriteChance = odds + 50
  print ("The favorite has a " + str(favoriteChance) + "% chance to win")
```

I want to use that percentage from this formula to run a simulation, where whatever team has that chance of winning. This is my first time self programming anything, sorry if this is really simple.

Comment: OK, and what is your question?

Comment: `won = random.randint(1,100) > odds`

Answer (score 2):

Good job with your first program. Many of us started out with much messier code.

If you don't mind I'm going to change your algorithm a little.
Currently your odds are `50% + (power1 - power2)`

This is annoying because if power values go beyond 50 it make a negative chance, or above 100, which doesn't work.

So if you don't mind let's change it to : `power1/(power1+power2)` and `power2/(power1+power2)`.

This has good properties:

- It is always positive (teams always have a chance to win, even if its really low)
- The sum is always equals to 1 (A team always wins)
- The chance to win is proportional to power (If power1 = 2*power2, then the chances of winning are also twice as big.

Alright now on to the code:

- I've never seen `requestInteger` before so I'll be using `input` instead.
- Since we want to announce a winner, I'll be adding inputs for the team names.
- I'll add a return value equal to the winning team, so you can do something with it via a `winner = main()` call.
- To check for a winner I'll check if `random.random` is bigger than the chance of `team1_win_chance`. `random.random` is evenly distributed between 0 and 1, so it being bigger than `team1_win_chance` is the same probability as team1 has of losing.
- If 1 doesn't win, since we have well defined probabilities then 2 wins by default.

Here's what the code looks like:

```py
import random

def main():
  team1 = input("Enter team 1 name:")
  power1 = int(input("Enter team 1 power:"))
  print(f"{team1}'s power is {power1}")
  team2 = input("Enter team 2 name:")
  power2 = int(input("Enter team 2 power:"))
  team1_win_chance = power1/(power1+power2)
  if random.random() > team1_win_chance:
    winner = team2
  else:
    winner = team1
  print(f"Team {winner} is the winner")
  return(winner)
```

And here is what it looks like when I run it:

```
>>> main()
Enter team 1 name:Turtles
Enter team 1 power:40
Turtles's power is 40
Enter team 2 name:Rabbits
Enter team 2 power:5
Team Turtles is the winner
'Turtles'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will probably look something like:

```
import random

def main():
  ...
  favoriteChance = odds + 50
  roll = random.randint(1, 100)
  win = roll <= favoriteChance
  if win:
    ... [print something indicating team 1 has won]
```

To step through that:

`import random` loads a package. When you are making more complicated programs, you can use this to load code from another file you've written, or code available online, but in this case we're loading the premade package `random`. Read the docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html, or do `help(random)`.

`roll = random.randint(1, 100)` generates a random number between 1 and 100. Think of it as rolling an 100-sided die. (When we call a function in the `random` package, we need to use `random.[functionname]`. That means that if you also happen to have a function with the same name in your file, it's clear which is which.)

`win = roll <= favoriteChance`: If we want a 70% chance of winning, one way to get that is to check if the die result is 1-70.

There's also lots of other functions in random, like for generating a random value between [0, 1), if you need more than 100 sides on your die.

Comment: it's an example of I hit enter too fast. Probably should have deleted and reposted  once I had finished editing @gre_gor